# JQueryMobile panel - how to always show on wide pages

Tags: jquery-mobile, panel, media-queries

I have a panel and am trying to always show the panel when the window is wide. I don't need to have a close button at all - just always show it for wider windows.

[jQuery Mobile Responsive Panel Dismiss issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167964/jquery-mobile-responsive-panel-dismiss-issue) helped, along with others, but no luck. I can get everything to almost work, but everytime I navigate to a new page, the panel animates in, which looks weird.

I am now looking at using a fixed div on the left that is not a jquerymobile panel. I can do this from the server. But it seems like a lot of effort to just keep a panel open.

Any hints?

Comment: I am having the same problem and I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", function( event, data ) {
    $('#my-panel').panel("open");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter such a problem. Here is my solution:
add the following javascript into your header:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", function( event, data ) {
    $('#my-panel').panel("open");
})
```

and in your panel add two attributes:data-swipe-close="false" , data-dismissible="false"

then the panel will be always shown in your html